# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type '((GetXState<DisposableInterface>) => void)?'

Tags: flutter, exception, idisposable, flutter-getx

I am working on a flutter project with GetX features in it but certainly I got some irrelevant and also according to me  surprising error which is mentioned above.

the first error causing code is

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:tajicEasy/controller/authController.dart';
import 'package:tajicEasy/controller/userController.dart';
import 'package:tajicEasy/ui/auth/login_in.dart';
import 'package:tajicEasy/ui/widgets/bottomNavigationBar.dart';

class LandingPage extends GetWidget<AuthController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetX(initState: maininit(),
        builder: (_) {
      print("here1");
      if (Get.find<AuthController>().user == "") {
        print("here1");
        return Login();
      } else {
        print("here1");
        return AppMain();
      }
    });
  }

  maininit() async {
    print("here");
    await Get.put<UserController>(UserController());
    print("here");
    await Get.put<AuthController>(AuthController());
    print("here");
  }
}
```

I am getting error after first here is printed that is in

```
await Get.put<UserController>(UserController());
```

Auth controller is initializing absolutely fine
my code for usercontroller is:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:tajicEasy/model/userModel.dart';
import 'package:tajicEasy/services/database.dart';

class UserController extends GetxController{
  var _userModel = UserModel().obs;

  UserModel get user => _userModel.value;

  set user(UserModel value) => this._userModel.value;
  Database _db = Database();

  bool enable = false;

  enabled(bool value) {
    print("here u");
    enable = !value;
    update();
  }

  void clear() {
    print("here u");
    _userModel.value = UserModel();
  }
}
```

I don't know much about GetX as I am working on it for the first time so please be lenient on me.

After this I am getting following error this error was removed as per the first answer from jahangir

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMVHK.png)

my code of splash activity is

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:tajicEasy/ui/auth/landingPage.dart';
import 'package:tajicEasy/ui/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'mySharedPreferences.dart';
import 'onBoarding_page.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myAppState();
  }

  bool isFirstTimeOpen = false;

  myAppState() {
    MySharedPreferences.instance
        .getBooleanValue("firstTimeOpen")
        .then((value) => setState(() {
              isFirstTimeOpen = value;
            })).then((value) => loadSplashScreen());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/logo.png",
          width: double.infinity,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Timer> loadSplashScreen() async {
    return Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), onDoneLoadind);
  }

  onDoneLoadind(){
    Get.offAll(() => {
      if(isFirstTimeOpen == true){
        LandingPage()
      }else{
        HomePage()
    }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `maininit()` function is an `async` function but you are not awaiting for it when calling in the `initState` of your `GetX` widget. So instead of returning the controller itself (UserController) it returns a boxed `Future<dynamic>.`

The solution is to make your `maininit()` function a normal function instead of an async function. That is:

```
  maininit() {
   print("here");
   Get.put<UserController>(UserController());
   print("here");
   Get.put<AuthController>(AuthController());
   print("here");
  }
```

There's no point making it an async function if you just use `Get.put` or `Get.lazyPut` instead of `Get.putAsync`.

Also, in my opinion most of the time you will use concrete classes for controllers. Therefore, it's completely unnecessary to use generic types when putting your controllers. So your `maininit()` should now look like this:

```
maininit() {
   print("here");
   Get.put(UserController());
   print("here");
   Get.put(AuthController());
   print("here");
  }
```

Comment: Tried it.... this give the error stating Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: Well, that's another problem. And your Page/Widget code seems unusual too. Can you please try `return GetX<AuthController>(initState: maininit(),..` and then `if (_.user == "") {..
` instead of `if (Get.find<AuthController>().user == "") {...
`

Comment: Also, is your `maininit()` is a class function? If so, I would recommend to make it a global or static function

Comment: still same error though the above problem is fixed but null value error is still there

Comment: Okay! First of all, shouldn't `loadSplashScreen();` be called after
    `myAppState();`? And please check that you are getting a boolean value and not null from your sharedpref. If you do, I would recommend you to move your `loadSplashScreen()` call inside of `then` of `myAppState()` right after the `setState`. Or maybe you could manage your splash screen more efficiently by using Getxcontroller.

Comment: I have  also tried calling ```loadSplashScreen();``` after setState then I got new error saying unexpected format you can see it in updataed code above for splash screen

Comment: I think you should move your logic to a controller. It will be more clean, simple and easy to understand. Also I am not sure if the `initState` method of a stateful widget can be made async or not but `onInit()` of a Getxcontroller surely can. Anyway, I think we are going off from the original topic. If you need further help regarding splash screen problem, you should create a new question. Oh! And don't forget to share that link here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67649858/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value-in-flutter-getx

Comment: this is the link yo new question brother